# How to set up MASTER_PORT and MASTER_ADDR in slurm

Tags: distributed, torch, slurm

In torch’s official documentation that talks about DDP, it said to set it as the following:

```
def setup(rank, world_size):
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = 'localhost'
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '12355'
```

and now I am using slurm to submit sbatch jobs, in this tutorial provided by Princeton University:
https://github.com/PrincetonUniversity/multi_gpu_training/tree/main/02_pytorch_ddp
it has the following setup:

```
export MASTER_PORT=$(expr 10000 + $(echo -n $SLURM_JOBID | tail -c 4))
master_addr=$(scontrol show hostnames "$SLURM_JOB_NODELIST" | head -n 1)
export MASTER_ADDR=$master_addr
echo "MASTER_ADDR="$MASTER_ADDR
```

But it seems even if I just keep the master_addr to localhost and master_port to 12355, and then submit it to slurm, it can still run.

Can anyone explain it a little bit more? For example, where does “12355” comes from , can it be random?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the port number is any random port over 1024 (those are reserved) that is available on your machine.